# Can I use a flush trim bit with a jig for kitchen worktop joints?

Tags: router

I'm looking to a do a 90 degrees join between kitchen worktops (countertops) and my router only goes up to 8mm bits, but I see most jigs need a 12mm or 1/2inch bit plus a bushing.
The moment I saw the worktops I didn't actually realize that you would use a bushing, and instead thought to use a flush trim bit to copy the shape of the jig.
Has anyone tried that before?

Here's an example of such a jig:
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. It's almost certain you need a larger router for this, if you can't stomach the purchase of a reasonable one of the right collet size can you borrow one off anyone you know?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your solution is that the jig pictured has an offset built in for the size of the bushing.

That means that one side won’t mate nicely with the other side, unless you jump through a bunch of calculation hoops. I’m not saying it’s impossible — it’s just going to take a lot of extra work. (Work that the jig usually simplifies.)

I admit that I have a bit of a problem with router proliferation, but my solution to this problem would be to buy or borrow a 1/2” router. The power will help cut the worktop and you’ll have another tool in your quiver for future projects.